# Sentence in Rhetorica ad Herennium

Tags: grammar-identification

> Iste, inquies, qui se dici divitem putat esse praeclarum, primum nunc videte, quo vultu nos intueatur: ...
> (*IV. 63*)

What's the structure of the **qui**-clause?

Should it be

> qui(*:=iste*) putat [se dici esse divitem] esse praeclarum
> *who thinks [that himself is said to be rich] is fine*
> (sorry if I translate it weirdly for I am not native speaker of English)

if I changed the word order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You understand the syntax correctly, although the fact that your translation isn't intelligible English leaves some doubt.

*iste quī* **sē dīcī dīvitem** *putat* esse praeclārum <=> “praeclārum est **cum ego dīves dīcor**” – *sīc iste putat*

The original translates to 'that guy, who thinks that him being called rich is a great thing'. There's no omitted *esse* in the *dīcī*-clause, it's a two-argument copular verb like *fierī* or *vocārī: quī dīves fit/vocātur/dīcitur.*